# I have 3 columns in my excel.A As Name ,B As Date and C AS time.now i want to show one line in which Name date and sum of time will come

Tags: excel, vba

```
Name    Date         time
Pooja   01-02-2015   03:05:45
pooja   01-02-2015   04:05:10
pooja   01-02-2015   07:05:03
pooja   02-02-2015   01:02:03  
pooja   02-02-2015   01:03:05
```

[image]

**result should be**:

```
Pooja 01-02-2015 14:15:58
pooja 02-02-2015 02:05:08
```

[image]

please suggest me how to write macro to get this result.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you want to achieve? A screenshot perhaps?

Comment: please check attached link

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you have a read of these links please [ASK] and [MCVE].  Could you give the question a title and move the actual question into the body of the text and make the question a lot easier to read - at the moment it's got links to images (which I can't see) pasted into the middle of the text.   It's all very confusing.

Comment: Can't you just use `=SUMIFS`? Do you need to do it for multiple sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code will collect the Names and Dates from `Sheet1`, copy them to `Sheet Sample` and `SumIfs()` the amount of hours in that day for that name.

```
Sub SumTimes()

    Dim arrNamesAndTimes As Variant

    'set last value found in A:A (names)
    Set last = Range("A:A").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    'for each name in range
    For n = 1 To last.Row
        'if is not in array already
        If Not InArray(Cells(n, 1).Value & " " & Cells(n, 2).Value, arrNamesAndTimes, 2) Then
            'add name and time to array
            If IsEmpty(arrNamesAndTimes) Then
                ReDim arrNamesAndTimes(0)
                arrNamesAndTimes(0) = Array(Cells(n, 1).Value, Cells(n, 2).Value, Cells(n, 1).Value & " " & Cells(n, 2).Value)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve arrNamesAndTimes(0 To UBound(arrNamesAndTimes) + 1)
                arrNamesAndTimes(UBound(arrNamesAndTimes)) = Array(Cells(n, 1).Value, Cells(n, 2).Value, Cells(n, 1).Value & " " & Cells(n, 2).Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'in sheet sample
    With Sheets("Sample")
        'for each of the collected names and days
        For n = LBound(arrNamesAndTimes) To UBound(arrNamesAndTimes)
            'put name and date one columns A and B
            .Cells(n + 1, 1).Value = arrNamesAndTimes(n)(0)
            .Cells(n + 1, 2).Value = arrNamesAndTimes(n)(1)
            'sum hours if name and date match
            .Cells(n + 1, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), arrNamesAndTimes(n)(0), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B"), arrNamesAndTimes(n)(1))
            'format cell to hours
            .Cells(n + 1, 3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Private Function InArray(val As String, arr As Variant, Optional oSet As Double) As Boolean

    InArray = False
    If IsEmpty(arr) Then Exit Function

    'check if name and date are already in array
    For n = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If (arr(n)(oSet) = val) Then
            InArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

You just need to assign this macro to your `command button`

Comment: Thank you so such Miguel_Ryu.Your code  resolved my issue.Thanks alot